# Elementary motivations for free resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, soft-question, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $R$ which admits a finite free resolution $0 \to F_n \to \dots \to F_0 \to M \to 0$. There is no doubt that knowing such a resolution is very useful in practice since it allows us to compute many invariants of $M$, such as homology groups, the rank of $M$, Betti numbers in the local case, or the Hilbert polynomial in the graded case. More generally, we can compute any invariant which is easily determined for free modules and behaves well under exact sequences.

While this all is clear for me, I am not able to explain the usefulness of finite free resolutions at an elementary level. Of course it always contains a finite presentation $F_1 \to F_0 \to M \to 0$ which I can motivate: With this data we are able to describe all elements of $M$ and to prove any equation which holds in $M$. In short: a finite presentation allows us to do calculations in $M$. But this explanation creates the impression that a finite presentation is all we need to understand the module $M$, doesn't it? Are there elementary reasons why we should be interested in higher syzygies?

Maybe this is a related question: What were the historical reasons to consider free resolutions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One might ask the same questions about higher Ext or Tor groups...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes but that's yet another story. I couldn't even motivate $\mathrm{Ext}_1$ or $\mathrm{Tor}^1$ at an elementary level.

Comment: @user26857: Something at the level of elements of $M$. For example: Can we benefit from a free resolution when we want to perform calculations in $M$? I tried to make my question clear by relating free resolutions to finite presentations, which actually make calculations in $M$ more precise (suppose $M$ is just an abstract object, not really concretely given).

Comment: Maybe it all depends on what you mean by elementary. If you are interested in depth, for instance, when $R$ is local or both $R, M$ graded, then certainly a presentation is not enough. In other words, if you are interested in the Cohen-Macaulayness of a module, then we need a (minimal) free resolution. Also, people do study infinite resolutions, too.

Comment: Here's a cutesy argument: if we're interested in presentations of modules we come across, and we come across the module of relations, then by induction we're interested in presenting modules of relations, equivalently, extending resolutions. Eh?

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Indeed, that is a good motivation. :)

Comment: "A free resolution may be thought of as the result of fully solving a system of linear equations $AX = 0$ with polynomial coefficients." A fuller description is given in the preface of Eisenbud's 'Geometry of Syzygies' https://books.google.ie/books?id=aXhCAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR12&ots=gt5yNvJEPI&pg=PR12#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score -1):

Intuitively, $M$ is an alternating sum of free modules.

Comment: Can you make this intuition more precise? I see that for example the rank of $M$ is the alternating sum of the ranks of free modules, but how should I think of an alternating sum of modules?